# Неправильно работает скролл в меню

Tags: javascript, html, css, foundation

Подробнее ниже в изображении.

Почему-то при посещении некоторых пунктов меню, сам контент скроллится в самый низ. Пытался исправлять это абсолютным позиционированием, свойством overflow, но не получилось. Может будут идеи, как это исправить, подскажите направление (ни в коем случае не прошу сделать за меня).
Кстати, на сайте используется framework foundation и slideout.js возможно неправильно их применил.

Адрес сайта:
https://sladosti38.ru/

[image: Меню с неправильным скроллом]

Comment: Есть решение через position: fixed, но тогда не будет скролла, если будут много пунктов меню

Comment: кажется понял в чем, проблема-скроллится общий блок, со всеми меню. А нужно сделать каждый независимый